# Performance issues in joining threads

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I wrote the following parallel code for examining all elements in a vector of vector. I store only those elements from `vector<vector<int> >` which satisfy a given condition. However, my problem is some of the vectors within `vector<vector<int> >` are pretty large while others are pretty small. Due to which my code takes a long time to perform thread.join(). Can someone please suggest as to how can I improve the performance of my code.

```
void check_if_condition(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& satisfyingElements)
{
    for(vector<int>::iterator i1=a.begin(), l1=a.end(); i1!=l1; ++i1)
        if(some_check_condition(*i1))
            satisfyingElements.push_back(*i1);

}

void doWork(std::vector<vector<int> >& myVec, std::vector<vector<int> >& results, size_t current, size_t end)
{
    end = std::min(end, myVec.size());
    int numPassed = 0;
    for(; current < end; ++current) {
        vector<int> satisfyingElements;
        check_if_condition(myVec[current], satisfyingElements); 
        if(!satisfyingElements.empty()){
            results[current] = satisfyingElements;            
        }
    }    
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > myVec(1000000);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > results(myVec.size());   
    unsigned numparallelThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    std::vector<std::thread> parallelThreads;
    auto blockSize = myVec.size() / numparallelThreads;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numparallelThreads - 1; ++i) {
        parallelThreads.emplace_back(doWork, std::ref(myVec), std::ref(results), i * blockSize, (i+1) * blockSize);
    }

    //also do work in this thread
    doWork(myVec, results, (numparallelThreads-1) * blockSize, myVec.size());

    for(auto& thread : parallelThreads)
        thread.join();

    std::vector<int> storage;
    storage.reserve(numPassed.load());

    auto itRes = results.begin();
    auto itmyVec = myVec.begin();
    auto endRes = results.end();
    for(; itRes != endRes; ++itRes, ++itmyVec) {
        if(!(*itRes).empty())
            storage.insert(storage.begin(),(*itRes).begin(), (*itRes).end());
    }

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for not saying the more readable `itres->begin()`? And `empty` should be a function call.

Comment: No reason as such but would if(itRes->begin()) and if(!(*itRes).empty()) have the same effect.

Comment: Obviously not, as they call different functions.

Comment: @latedeveloper Ok. Which one amongst them will be more efficient?

Comment: I thought the pattern is to chop the sequences into reasonably sized chunks and process them as jobs in a thread pool. You'll probably have a comparatively large number jobs compared to the number of jobs. This way things should balance more effectively.

Comment: `results[current] = satisfyingElements;` shouldn't compile. It's trying to assign `vector<int>` to `vector<bool>`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah...sorry ...its a typo....vector<int>

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to see if you can give some scale of those 'large' inner-vectors just to see how bad is the problem.

I think however, is that your problem is this:

```
for(auto& thread : parallelThreads)
    thread.join();
```

This bit makes goes through on all thread sequentially and wait until they finish, and only then looks at the next one. For a thread-pool, you want to wait until every thread is done. This can be done by using condition_variable for each thread to finish. Before they finish they have to notify the condition_variable for which you can wait.

Looking at your implementation the bigger issue here is that your worker threads are not balanced in their consumption.

To get a more balanced load on all of your threads, you need to flatten your data structure, so the different worker threads can process relatively similar sized chunks of data. I am not sure where is your data coming from, but having a vector of a vector in an application that is dealing with large data sets doesn't sound like a great idea. Either process the existing vector of vectors into a single one, or read the data in like that if possible. If you need the row number for your processing, you can keep a vector of start-end ranges from which you can find your row number.

Once you have a single big vector, you can break it down to equal sized chunks to feed into worker threads. Second, you don't want to build vectors on the stack handing and pushing them into another vector because, chances are, you are running into issues to allocate memory during the working of your threads. Allocating memory is a global state change and as such will require some level of locking (with proper address partitioning it could be avoided though). As a rule of thumb, whenever your are looking for performance you should remove dynamic allocation from performance critical parts.

In this case, perhaps your threads would rather 'mark' elements are satisfying conditions, rather than building vectors of the satisfying elems. And once that's done, you can iterate through only the good ones without pushing and copying anything. Such solution would be less wastefull.

In fact, if I were you, I would give a try to solve this issue first on a single thread, doing the suggestions above. If you get rid of the vector-of-vectors structure, and iterate through elements conditionally (this might be as simple as using the of the xxxx_if algorithms C++11 standard library provides), you could end up with a decent enough performance. And only at that point worth looking at delegating chunks of this work to worker threads. At this point in your coded there's very little justification to use worker threads, just to filter them. Do as little writing and moving as you can, and you gain a lot of performance. Parallelization only works well in certain circumstances.